# iOS TableView inside of a CollectionView sometimes shows incorrect data

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a collectionView where I show a list of comments in a tableView. I see that the tableView data is not the correct one when the collectionView is scrolled.

I tried to remedy that using prepareForReuse() which did not work. Here is my code :

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        imageView.image = UIImage()
        commentsTableView = UITableView()
    }
```

I would appreciate if someone can suggest a solution for this.

Thanks.

Comment: show us your code for CollectionView and TableView

Answer (score 0):

Assign all your properties to nil.

```
override func prepareForReuse() {

        imageView.image = nil
        commentsTableView = nil
        super.prepareForReuse()
    }
```

But make sure that your properties is optional.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I will try it out and let you know if this worked. Is there a reason why super.prepareForReuse() is at the end ? Generally, in the overriden view functions , we call the super class method in the beginning of the function.

Comment: I tried but that didnt solve it unfortunately. Still see wrong data sometimes which gets corrected when the table reloads ( on scrolling )

Comment: Oh can you check constraint your item in your table cell. make it is all correct.